# How do we resolve conflicting behaviours warnings in Elixir

Tags: elixir, warnings, behavior

How may we resolve conflicting behaviours warnings in Elixir?

```
warning: conflicting behaviours found. function handle_info/2 is required by Raxx.Server and GenServer
```

For example, I need to use both `GenServer` and `Raxx.SimpleServer` in a modeule, and both define the `@callback` `handle_info`

```
defmodule TestServer
 use Raxx.SimpleServer
 use GenServer

 def handle_info(_, state), do: {:noreply, state}    
end
```

Please what's the best/recommended workaround for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR:** you cannot suppress this warning because you are not supposed to cross-violate behaviours. OTOH, it’s just a convention and the code would probably happily run despite the warning.

---

This is surely an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). In the first place, you should explicitly tell the compiler that `handle_info/2` is an implementation:

```
@impl GenServer # or @impl true
def handle_info(_, state), do: {:noreply, state}
```

Secondarily, the design as stated, even if it was welcome and did not produce any warning, violates [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

What you probably should do, is a supervision tree with a supervisor, managing two workers: one for `Raxx.SimpleServer`, and another one for `GenServer`. When the interoperation is required, you should pass the message to the respective process.

Answer (score 1):

`use Raxx.SimpleServer` will automatically set the `@behaviour GenServer`, so your use is duplicated. Remove your `@behaviour GenServer` (or `Rax.SimpleServer`) line and it will fix your warnings :)

Comment: this didn't help much. I had to into two modules eventually